# Using a forked expo package

Tags: react-native, expo, customization, git-fork

I want to use a forked expo package in my expo app instead of the official expo.
I am trying to do something like this
`expo: ' git+https://github.com/alexbrazier/expo.git#disable-notification-entitlement`

but in yarn add or npm install it fails and throws errors

can anyone guide please?

yarn add  git+https://github.com/alexbrazier/expo.git#disable-notification-entitlement